# failed to open file 'load_departments.dump'; error: 2

Tags: import, mysql-workbench

I am trying to import a the employees.sql database from GitHub but I get the following error message

> ERROR at line 113: Failed to open file 'load_departments.dump', error:
>   2

I am importing the database using the 'Data Import' option from the 'Server' drop down menu.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're using MS SQL Server and not MySQL?

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench